# Format CSV From Object

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am trying to figure out how to create a .csv from a PowerShell object that has the appropriate columns. I want to create a .csv file with three columns (User ID, Country, Count). It also needs to sort by User ID and then Country (A to Z). In the example code below, I want the output to be like this:

```
User ID, Country, Count
Bob, China, 2
Joe, Canada, 1
Joe, United States, 1
```

```js
$path = "C:\test\test.csv"
Set-Content -Path $path -Value “UserId, Country”
Add-Content -Path $path -Value "Joe, United States", "Bob, China", "Bob, China", "Joe, Canada"
(Import-Csv -Path $path) | Group-Object -Property UserID, Country -NoElement | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Values, Group | Select-Object @{Name="User ID, Country";Expression={$_.Name}}, Count | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Force
Get-Content -Path $path
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, User ID and Country are in the same column as below:

```
"User ID, Country","Count"
"Joe, United States","1"
"Bob, China","2"
"Joe, Canada","1"
```

I believe the problem stems from `Select-Object @{Name="User ID, Country";Expression={$_.Name}}`. How can I get this to be in three columns sorted as requested above? As a bit of an aside, I do not fully understand the syntax of the problem code. If you could explain what the `@{Name="User ID, Country";Expression={$_.Name}}` does, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**
Here is my actual code in case this helps with the problem at all.

```js
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$lastMonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1)
$startDate = get-date -year $lastMonth.Year -month $lastMonth.Month -day 1
$endDate = ($startDate).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
$operation = UserLoginFailed
$path = "C:\Failed Logins $($lastMonth.ToString("yyyy_MM")).csv"

Set-Content -Path $path -Value “UserId, Country”
Function Connect-EXOnline {
    $credentials = Get-Credential -Credential $credential     
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
        -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential $credentials `
        -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber
}
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-EXOnline

$Logs = @()
do {
    $logs += Search-unifiedAuditLog -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -SessionId "UALSearch" -ResultSize 5000 -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -Operations $operation
}while ($Logs.count % 5000 -eq 0 -and $logs.count -ne 0)
 
$userIds = $logs.userIds | Sort-Object -Unique
 
foreach ($userId in $userIds) {
    $ips = @()
    $searchResult = ($logs | Where-Object {$_.userIds -contains $userId}).auditdata | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    $ips = $searchResult.clientip
    foreach ($ip in $ips) {
        $mergedObject = @{}
        $singleResult = $searchResult | Where-Object {$_.clientip -contains $ip} | Select-Object -First 1
        Start-sleep -m 400
        $ipresult = Invoke-restmethod -method get -uri http://ip-api.com/json/$ip
        $UserAgent = $singleResult.extendedproperties.value[0]
        $singleResultProperties = $singleResult | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
        foreach ($property in $singleResultProperties) {
            if ($property.Definition -match "object") {
                $string = $singleResult.($property.Name) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
                $mergedObject | Add-Member -Name $property.Name -Value $string -MemberType NoteProperty    
            }
            else {$mergedObject | Add-Member -Name $property.Name -Value $singleResult.($property.Name) -MemberType NoteProperty}          
        }
        $property = $null
        $ipProperties = $ipresult | get-member -MemberType NoteProperty
 
        foreach ($property in $ipProperties) {
            $mergedObject | Add-Member -Name $property.Name -Value $ipresult.($property.Name) -MemberType NoteProperty
        }
        $mergedObject | Select-Object UserId, Country  | Export-Csv $path -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

(Import-Csv -Path $path) | Group-Object -Property UserID, Country -NoElement | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Values, Group | Select-Object @{Name="User ID, Country";Expression={$_.Name}}, Count | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Basically, I will have a .csv file that contains a bunch of email addresses and failed login attempts by country. The last line is used to count how many failed attempts each email address has from each company. This is where the problem is.

Comment: `Group-Object` with -NoElement will leave you only the properties Count,Name where Name consists of UserId and Country delimited with comma space. You'll need **two** calculated properties to split them again.

Comment: How much powershell do you already know?  In particular,  have you ever used Export-Csv on the right side of a pipeline?

Comment: Here's a silly example:  Get-Process | Export-Csv myfile.csv

Comment: @LotPings That makes sense. I did a bit of searching on how to do this, and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @WalterMitty I am  very new when it comes to PowerShell. I have used Export-Csv on the right side of a pipeline, however.

Comment: @LotPings I just found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730948(v=technet.10) which discusses calculated properties! It worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your problem statement, in order to tackle one issue at a time.
I set out to solve the simple problem of producing the output CSV file you want from
the input CSV file you stated.  I created the input file with notepad, instead of with powershell.

Here is what I came up with:

```
<# Summarizes log by user and country.   #>

Import-csv logfile.csv |
    Sort-Object  UserID, Country |
    Group-Object UserID, Country | 
    foreach { $b = $_.name -split ', '
        [PSCustomobject] @{UserID = $b[0]; Country= $b[1]; Count=$_.count}}|
    Export-Csv summary.csv

Import-Csv logfile.csv | Format-table
Import-Csv summary.csv | Format-table
```

The last two steps just display the input and the output CSV files.  This is what it looked like when I ran it.

```
UserID Country      
------ -------      
Joe    United States
Bob    China        
Bob    China        
Joe    Canada       



UserID Country       Count
------ -------       -----
Bob    China         2    
Joe    Canada        1    
Joe    United States 1
```

Comment: The primary tool used to make this answer simple and readable is the pipeline.  If you are new to Powershell and to pipelines,  take the time to learn how to use pipelines to good advantage,  (and when not to try to use them).  Even if you have used pipelines in some other environment, you may find that Powershell pipelines are more powerful than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you'll need **two** calculated properties to split the Name again.

```
(Import-Csv $path) | Group-Object 'User ID',Country -NoElement | 
    Select-Object @{n='UserID';e={($_.Name -split ', ')[0]}},
                  @{n='Country';e={($_.Name -split ', ')[1]}},
                  Count | Export-Csv $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

This will yield the same output as Walter Mitty's solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your life much easier when you use the availabe built in cmdlets for CSV data like this:

```
$path = 'C:\test\test.csv'
$Data = @'
UserID,Country,Count
Bob,China,2
Joe,Canada,1
Joe,United States,1
'@

ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -InputObject $Data -OutVariable CSVData
$CSVData | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
```

You simply build your data as you need it completely and you convert it or export it in once.

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable. I will edit my post to contain the code I am actually working on.

Comment: Wow, that's a big chunk of confusing code. You might make a step back and take a little time to learn the very basics of Powershell. You're trying to iteratively create a csv file step by step or line by line. That's not the way we do things in Powershell. You should create ALL the data you want to export first and export them in once when you're finished.